# How to inject HTML into a template with polymer

Tags: javascript, json, polymer

I'm using polymer-jsonp to perform JSONP requests, but the response sometimes contains html.

For example, supposing that post.content is `"<strong>Foo</strong> bar"`, how can I display {{post.content}} such that `"Foo"` is in bold?

```
<polymer-element name="feed-element" attributes="">
  <template>
    <template repeat="{{post in posts.feed.entry}}">
      <p>{{post.content}}</p>
    </template>
    <polymer-jsonp url="url" response="{{posts}}"></polymer-jsonp>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('feed-element', {
      created: function() { },
      attached: function() { },
      detached: function() { },
      attributeChanged: function(attrName, oldVal, newVal) { }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: You could easy do:
<div inner-h-t-m-l="{{item.content}}"></div> > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30678307/polymer-1-0-how-to-bind-html-value (Peter)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Polymer will not stamp unescaped HTML via data-binding because it becomes a vulnerability for XSS attacks.

There are talks ongoing about making it possible to stamp HTML under limited circumstance, or to allow for customized filtering, but this is not implemented yet at the data layer.

It is possible to do what you want today using an additional custom element, but again, be advised of the potential for bad things to happen if you render untrusted HTML into your page.

Here is an example that shows this technique:

http://jsbin.com/durajiwo/1/edit

Comment: Example of Scott's technique using Flickr's jsonp API and `<polymer-jsonp>`: http://jsbin.com/zoduhoqu/1/edit

Comment: Is juicy-html also vulnerable to XSS attacks ? I guess the answer is positive, but just checking

Comment: @Scott, could you comment more on the need for additional element for this to work?

Comment: You don't *need* to have an additional element. You can always just do `this.innerHTML = ...`. The idea is that we cannot allow you to directly bind data to HTML, without you doing _something_ to explicitly enter in to the danger zone. Some folks use preprocessors that attempt to explicitly forbid `innerHTML`, other teams require input sanitizers. There are a variety of solutions, and we can improve in this area.

Answer (score 9):

For those look for polymer 1.0

```
<dom-module id="html-echo">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  (function () {
    Polymer({
      is: 'html-echo',
      properties: {
        html: {
          type: String,
          observer: '_htmlChanged'
        }
      },
      _htmlChanged: function (neo) {
        // WARNING: potential XSS vulnerability if `html` comes from an untrusted source
        this.innerHTML = neo;
      }
    });
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: Bear in mind, since binding is statically calculated at pre-render time, your imperative declarations like `[[foo]]` or `{{bar}}` will not work in your new html since they're added post render.

Comment: how we can call post render in this method ?

Comment: `this.innerHTML = postProcess(neo);` does this fit for you ?@Ali.MD

Comment: I think in Polymer 1.0 the <style> tag is supposed to be inside the <template> tags, but otherwise I wish I could +1 this answer twice. You saved me so much heartache; thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure it is what you want to do, just use `innerHTML`.

```
_renderHtml: function(html) {
  this.$.dynamicHtmlContainer.innerHTML = html;
}
```

Or to dynamically add a shadow-dom child:

```
_renderHtml: function(html) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = html;
  Polymer.dom(this).appendChild(div);
}
```

I think `Polymer.dom` is being removed in Polymer 2.0 though.