# How to distribute (insert) content nodes programmatically

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

Is there a way to programmatically distribute (insert) content from lightDOM to ShadowDOM?

I would like to wrap every single child node into an element.
For example :

```
<my-list>
  <span>first element</span>
  <div>second element</div>
  <a>third element</a>
</my-link>
```

to be distributed as

```
<my-list>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>first element</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>second element</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>third element</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</my-link>
```

I need it not only to render that way, but also delegate entire HTML behavior (bindings, events, etc..) as each distributed node may contain entire app.

I have tried appending `<content select=":nth-child(..)">` elements to template on `attached` callback

```
attached: function(){
    //ensure any element upgrades have been processed
    this.async(function asyncAttached(){
        var list = this.$.container;
        this.children.array().forEach(function(child, childNo){
            var li = document.createElement("LI");
            console.log(list, li, child);
            li.innerHTML = '<content select=":nth-child('+childNo+')"></content>';
            list.appendChild(li);
        });
    });
}
```

But it does not work (probably because content was already distributed).

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tomalec/b5Nqt/1/)

In general what I would like to achieve is something like http://jsbin.com/hegizi/3/edit, but without hard-coding class names, and make it work with variable number of child nodes.

What is more, it seems, that `:nth-child` is not supported natively: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/470

Answer (score 2):

Composition is something Shadow DOM is designed for. If that spec bug gets fixed, the best way to do this would be interesting tricks with `<content select=":nth-child(...)">` in a `<template repeat>`. Since you can't (currently) use `:nth-child`, you could instead use the distributed nodes and data-binding to wrap the content:

```
<template repeat="{{node in nodes}}">
  <li>
    <html-echo html="{{node.outerHTML}}"></html-echo>
  </li>
</template>
<content id="c" select="*"></content>
```

`nodes` is generated from something like:

```
this.nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.$.c.getDistributedNodes());
```

I'm using `<html-echo>` from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22208332/274673

Working demo: http://jsbin.com/mamawugo/2/edit

Comment: Thanks @ebidel, works nice for rendering. However, if I get it right, your example does not distribute content the way `<content>` does. It only copies text. What I need it to distribute node which may contain entire app inside. Here is simplified case: http://jsbin.com/robaw/3/edit <- just click event listener.

Comment: @ebidel Could you "hack" this by assigning unique attributes to the content-nodes programatically and inserting `<content>` nodes which selects based on said attributes?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564150/decorate-elements-from-content/25565699#25565699 for an example of what Alxandr suggests.

Answer (score 0):

There is quite old issue at W3C Bugzilla: [#18429 - [Shadow]: Specify imperative API for node distribution](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=18429)

But as for now, there is nothing in spec about that.