# Polymer 1.0 - How to bind html value

Tags: polymer

I have a list of items in which each item has a .content html value as following.

```
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{entries}}">
    <li><p class="paper-font-body2">{{item.title}}</p>
      <div>{{item.content}}</div></li>
  </template>
```

content field is somewhat like this

```
  Hello <strong>Polymer</strong>
```

It shows in browser as plain text. How do I show it as safe html?

EDIT: this issue is [raised](https://github.com/Polymer/TemplateBinding/issues/57), but it doesn't help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to inject HTML into a template with polymer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199662/how-to-inject-html-into-a-template-with-polymer)

Answer (score 18):

You could easily do:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{entries}}">
    <li><p class="paper-font-body2">{{item.title}}</p>
      <div inner-h-t-m-l="{{item.content}}"></div></li>
  </template>
```

That's what I'm using, bearing in mind that XSS vulnerability is open.

Comment: This worked fine for me. However in my case style classes are not applied to the bound html.

Answer (score 6):

You could try something like this:

```
<dom-module id="echo-html">

  <template>
    <span>{{html}}</span>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'echo-html',
      properties: {
          html: {
              type: String,
              value: 'html'
          }
      },
      ready: function() {
          this.innerHTML = this.html;
      }
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

and call it like that I guess:

```
<div><echo-html html="{{item.content}}"></echo-html></div>
```

Comment: Very elegant. Not sure why this.innerHTML, this is what worked for me in a similar situation:

    Polymer({
      is: 'ir-gallery-echo-html',
      properties: {
          html: {
              type: String,
              value: 'html',
     observer : 'htmlChanged'
          }
      },
      htmlChanged: function() {
  this.$.content.innerHTML = this.html;
          //this.innerHTML = this.html;
      }
    });