# Unsanitize HTML for a Polymer repeating element dom-repeat

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to get HTML displayed from data coming back from an API. Yes, I understand there is XSS consequences, but it's from a trusted HTTPS source.

The code is:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{response}}" id="eventList">
    <h2>{{item.EventName}}</h2>
    {{item.Description}}
</template>
```

I've seen some questions on how to do it for individual sections, but not for a dom-repeat.

Thanks!

Comment: Well I did find this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30678307/polymer-1-0-how-to-bind-html-value and it worked, but I was really hoping there was a better solution.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636107/iroin-ajax-response-with-html-tags