# Result Ajax HTML in Polymer

Tags: polymer-1.0

```
<iron-ajax
      auto
      url= 'http://localhost/sh_new/index.php/mobile/notes/{{misi}}'
      handle-as="document"
      on-response="handleResponse"
      last-response = "{{noteResponse}}">
</iron-ajax>
    {{noteResponse}}
```

result is `[object HTMLDocument]`  how to change into html

Comment: I guess you need some kine of helper element like shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199662/how-to-inject-html-into-a-template-with-polymer

Answer (score 0):

Change **handle-as="document"** to **handle-as="html"**

Use underscore.js utility named **_.template** to convert it into HTML. It is basically used to load partial HTML content. I know this is not good one solution but it will solve your purpose.

```js
app.handleResponse = function(e, detail){
  var html = _.template(detail.response);
}

<iron-ajax
      auto
      url= 'http://localhost/sh_new/index.php/mobile/notes/{{misi}}'
      handle-as="html"
      on-response="handleResponse"
      last-response = "{{noteResponse}}">
</iron-ajax>
    {{noteResponse}}
```

Comment: if i change handle-as ="document" to handle-as="html" result in tag not html