# Polymer inline conditional, or, how do I display a loading image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, polymer

If I wanted to display a loading image and I was using JQuery to populate my data, I would do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="loadthis"><img src="loading.gif"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#loadthis').html("Received Data");
```

However, with Polymer, my template looks like this:

```
<div id="loadthis">{{receiveddata}}</div>
```

and I have this property:

```
Polymer({
    is: 'test-loading',
    properties: {
        receiveddata: {
            type: String,
            value: ''
        }
    }
});
```

I have tried simply putting html in the value for `receiveddata` but [quickly discovered that won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199662/how-to-inject-html-into-a-template-with-polymer).  I've also tried `moustache` syntax of `{{#if}}` etc, but that didn't work at all.

How can I display an image until the `receiveddata` property is populated?

Comment: You can use `.innerHTML` to stamp html through variables

Comment: As for displaying image till `receiveData` has value you can use `dom-if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @a1626's comment mentioning `dom-if` I came up with this solution:

```
<div id="loadthis">
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{isloading}}">
        <img src="loading.gif">
    </template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{!isloading}}">
        {{receiveddata}} 
    </template>
</div>
```

Then I added an `isloading` property in my Polymer definition.

```
Polymer({
    is: 'test-loading',
    properties: {
        receiveddata: {
            type: String,
            value: ''
        },    
        isloading: {
            type: Boolean,
            value: true
        }
    }
});
```

Now I just set it to false when the data has loaded.

```
self.isloading = false;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to load local image dynamically, you should load it with full address.

For example, your `loading.gif` image is under folder `/images/loading.gif` or `/views/loading/loading.gif`. Though you can use it like `<img src="loading.gif">` statically, once you want to use it dynamically, you should write `this.receiveData = '<img src= "/images/loading.gif">';` or `this.receiveData = '<img src= "/views/loading/loading.gif">';`