# html response in a iron-ajax request

Tags: polymer

My iron-ajax response an object like this:

```
{
   "id": "1",
   "idcontenido": "7",
   "imagenes": ["carabela.png", "DSC_9565.png"],
   "tipo_imagen": "img-circle",
   "html": "Esta <b>regi\u00f3n<\/b>"
}
```

Some ids, an array images... and one 'html' attribute.

This is my element template:

```
<template>
   ...
   <p>[[ajaxResponse.html]]</p>

<iron-ajax 
        id="ajax" 
        url="..." 
        handle-as="json" 
        verbose=true 
        last-response={{ajaxResponse}} 
        loading="{{cargando}}"> </iron-ajax>
   ...
</template>
```

So I want to write the html code from server in my page, but when showing the page, the html code is not being interpretated and I can read literally:

```
Esta <b>región</b>
```

How can I fix this interpretated the html code?
Thanks!

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199662/how-to-inject-html-into-a-template-with-polymer/22208332#22208332

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have fix this with an on-response method for the iron-ajax element:

```
_onResponse: function (e) {
   this.$.html.innerHTML = e.detail.response.html;
}
```

e.detail.response contains an object with a 'html' attribute, the html code I want to write in my page in a 'p' tag with id=html